# clicking on select box hides CSS drop down

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a CSS drop down block as follows, The drop down block contains a `select` box. Everything works as expected except the select box. As soon as I click on the select box the block disappears. Here is a [**`JSFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gTbyE/) showing the exact problem:

```
#ddul {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 15px;
    list-style: None;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:5px;
    left:0;
}

.dd:hover ul#ddul {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
}
```

what could be a possible reason for such behavior ? Thanks.

#### Update:

Just realized it works fine on Firefox but not on Chrome.

#### Update:

Works on chrome as well on a MAC, but not on Ubuntu (Ubuntu V.12.04)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `active`pseudo class on the hidden element solves this.

```
ul#ddul:active,
.dd:hover ul#ddul {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason might be that when you select an item the `<ul></ul>` moves up again. So the position of your mouse is under the ul section -> it isn't hovered anymore -> no more visible drop down

**How to solve it (not too gentle way I guess):**

1/ If you don't like it this way you can just set (minimum) height for that hovered `<div>` so u will be with your mouse over the div even when selecting one of the select.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/goodfriend/gTbyE/4/

2/ Putting the select on top of the menu or what that is will also do the magic I think :]

Comment: I think it is a bug with chrome as it is working fine on other browsers

Comment: Maybe FF isn't so strict or the ul area is bigger there.. it has custom margins i think. I always had issues with different padding/margin for `<ul></ul>` and `<li></li>`. IE on this PC won't even show jsfiddle.net properly so .. :D